# How to arrange latest post at the top in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As in Firebase real-time database since the newest node/post is put at the bottom, is there any way to arrange them in reverse order i.e. latest post at the top?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this, we can use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP . Below code will explain. Instead of pudhId here we have to use 'postId' as Firebase pushId which will be a number

final HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("currentTime", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    databaseReference.child("CurrentTime").child(mUser.getUid()).updateChildren(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {

`databaseReference.child("CurrentTime").child(mUser.getUid()).child("currentTime").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Long serverTime = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);

                if(serverTime != null){

                    BigInteger constant = new BigInteger("9999999999999");
                    BigInteger currentTime = BigInteger.valueOf(serverTime);
                    BigInteger writeTime = constant.subtract(currentTime);
                    final String postId = String.valueOf(writeTime);

                 }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
});`